# If $1, \omega_1,\omega_2...\omega_6$ are $7^{th}$ roots of unity, then find the value of $Im(\omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_4)$

Tags: complex-numbers

$\omega_1$ and $\omega_6$ are conjugate pairs. The same applies for for $\omega_2$ and $\omega_5$ and so on.

So 
$$\omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_4=a+ib$$
$$\omega_6+\omega_5+\omega_3=a-ib$$

$$\implies -1=2a$$
$$\implies a=-\frac 12$$

What should I do next ?

Comment: Find $(a+ib)(a-ib)$. Note $1+\omega_1+...+\omega_6=0$.

Comment: @Somos, that's a solution.

Comment: What form do you want the result in? Obviously it's equal to $\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{8\pi}{7}$, but are you supposed to express that explicitly as an algebraic number? According to Wolfram Alpha, it's just [$\frac{\sqrt 7}{2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%282pi%2F7%29%2Bsin%284pi%2F7%29%2Bsin%288pi%2F7%29).

Comment: @TonyK $\frac{\sqrt 7}{2}$ is the right answer. That’s the form required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{\pi}7$. Then, the roots are $w_k=e^{i2ka}$ and,

$$A=Im(\omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_4)=\sin2a+\sin4a+\sin8a$$

Evaluate

$$A^2 = \sin^22a+\sin^24a+\sin^28a + 2\sin2a\sin4a+2\sin4a\sin8a+2\sin8a\sin2a\tag 1$$

where,

$$\begin{array}
&& \sin^22a+\sin^24a+\sin^28a \\
& = \frac12(3-\cos4a-\cos8a-\cos16a)=\frac32+\frac12(\cos a+\cos3a+\cos5a) \\
& 2\sin2a\sin4a+2\sin4a\sin8a+2\sin8a\sin2a \\
& =(\cos2a-\cos6a)+(\cos4a-\cos12a)+(\cos6a-\cos10a) \\
& =(\cos2a-\cos6a)+(\cos4a-\cos2a)+(\cos6a-\cos4a) =0
\end{array}$$

Then, the expression (1) becomes

$$\begin{array}
& A^2 & = \frac32+\frac12(\cos a+\cos3a+\cos5a) \\
& = \frac32+\frac1{2\sin a}(\cos a\sin a+\cos3a\sin a+\cos5a\sin a)\\
& = \frac32+\frac1{4\sin a}(\sin2a+\sin4a -\sin2a + \sin6a -\sin4a )\\
& = \frac32+\frac{\sin6a}{4\sin a}=\frac32+\frac{1}{4}=\frac74
\end{array}$$

Thus,

$$Im(\omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_4) = A = \frac{\sqrt7}2$$

Comment: How did $\cos 16a$ become $\cos 5a$?

Comment: @Aditya - Note $\cos16a  = \cos(2\pi + 2a) = \cos2a = - \cos 5a$

Comment: Why not just leave it as $\cos 2a$

Comment: @Aditya - you could. Then, adjust the derivation afterwards

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The quadratic residues modulo $7$ are precisely $1$, $2$ and $4$.

---

Alternatively, you could use the fact that
$$\omega_k=\cos(\tfrac{2\pi}{7}k)+\sin(\tfrac{2pi}{7}k)i,$$
to note that
$$\operatorname{Im}(\omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_3)=\sin(\tfrac{2pi}{7})+\sin(2\tfrac{2pi}{7})+\sin(4\tfrac{2pi}{7}).$$
Perhaps you could then aply some trigonometric identities if this expression isn't satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The roots of $$\dfrac{x^7-1}{x-1}=0$$  are $w_j, 1\le j\le6$

Also, $w_j\cdot w_k=w_{j+k}$

$(w_1+w_2+w_4)(w_3+w_5+w_6)$

$=w_4+w_5+w_7+w_6+w_7+w_9+w_7+w_8+w_{10}$

$=w_4+w_5+1+w_6+1+w_2+1+w_1+w_3=2+(\sum_{j=0}^6w_j)=2$

So, $w_1+w_2+w_4,w_3+w_5+w_6$  are the roots of $$t^2-t+2=0$$

Again $$\sin\dfrac{2\pi}7+\sin\dfrac{4\pi}7+\sin\dfrac{8\pi}7=2\sin\dfrac{5\pi}7\cos\dfrac{3\pi}7+\sin\dfrac{4\pi}7>0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\omega_{1}+\omega_{2}+\omega_{4})^{2}&=(\omega_{1}+\omega_{2}+\omega_{4})+2(\omega_{3}+\omega_{5}+\omega_{6})\\
(\omega_{1}+\omega_{2}+\omega_{4})^{2}&=(\omega_{1}+\omega_{2}+\omega_{4})+2(-1-(\omega_{1}+\omega_{2}+\omega_{4}))
\end{aligned}
$$

So the positive imaginary root of $m^{2}=-m+2$ which is $\frac{-1+i\sqrt{7}}{2}$

Comment: I think this is something I don’t know. Why did $2(\omega_1\omega_2+2\omega_2\omega_4+\omega_4\omega_1)$ turn into $2(\omega_3+\omega_5+\omega_6)$

Comment: @Aditya because if $\omega$ is roots of unity then $\omega_{n}=\omega^{n}$

Comment: Wait, isn’t $\omega_3=\omega^2$, since the roots are $1,\omega,\omega^2...$?

Comment: typically, the first root is $\omega$ since $1=\omega^{7}$

Comment: So the roots are $\omega, \omega^2,\omega^3....\omega^6, 1$? This doesn’t feel right, because I have always known that it starts with 1.

Comment: @Aditya that is ok too, since from Your title $\omega_{1}=\omega$ thus we still have $\omega_{n}=\omega^{n}$